# Selecting all first tier elements of another first tier element

Tags: jquery

Is there a more elegant way to select all the first tier `<dt>`s than what I am showing.  I was thinking something like `$('#myDiv').children('dl>dt')` but it doesn't work. Thanks

```
$('#myDiv dl').children('dt');
$('#myDiv').children('dl').children('dt');


    <div id="myDiv">
        <dl>
            <dt>good</dt>
            <dd>good
            <dl><dt>Bad</dt><dd>Bad</dd></dl>
            </dd>
            <dt>good</dt><dd>good</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by first tier? and your example looks to be wrong. I think you are closing tags that you don't actually open

Comment: Sorry about the HTML.  It is fixed (unless dls can't go in a dt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv>dl>dt')
```

That is *black* **magic**!

Comment: Thanks Neal.  What if I start with an object which is equal to $('#myDiv'). It happens to be this of a dialog.

Comment: I open a dialog, and this is set as the dialog div.  For portability of code, I would rather not reference the ID again.

Comment: @user1032531 that is a completely different question and out of the scope of this one.

Comment: Agree.  Answer selected (in 4 minutes), but if you can comment, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Learn the CSS selectors. They're quite handy when using jQuery.

The CSS selector to get the direct children is: `>`

So:

```
$('#myDiv > dl > dt')
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this one:

```
$('#myDiv dl dt')
```